# Train Mask R-CNN with some classes having no masks but only bounding boxes

Tags: computer-vision, conv-neural-network, image-segmentation, faster-rcnn, detectron

I want to train a model to detect three different types of defects. I have a training dataset where two of these classes contain segmentation masks, but one contains only bounding boxes. Can I train a shared model or do I need to separate the training dataset and train a Faster R-CNN and a Mask R-CNN?

(I only care about bounding box output for the class containing no masks in the training data.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create *'weak'* masks from those bounding boxes and then combine those two datasets. Something like below:

```
mask = np.zeros((256, 256), dtype=np.float32)
mask[y:y+h, x:x+w] = 255.
```

If the two datasets are small, combining them will yield better results. But if the datasets are big enough (>2000 images) then you can use `FasterRCNN` + `MaskRCNN` approach.